# <br> being ignored when updating innerHTML on ios/ipados

Tags: ios, safari, innerhtml, html-rendering

**[EDIT: Apple replied.  It was caused by new permanent behaviour introduced by Safari conforming to a draft of the css spec.  I figured out an easy workaround and posted it as an answer]**

I recently reported to Apple that, after updating to IPADOS 17.2, Safari ignores the `<br>` tag when updating the innerHTML of an element.

[image]

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/arpace/ox65qm17/)

Not sure if it is effecting more than just iframes, as I just discovered it, and I don't have a workaround just yet.

This is going to be annoying until Apple fixes the issue, so if anyone else has noticed this, what is your workaround?

This is strange behaviour!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to figure out that the issue was caused by how Safari, after updating to IPADOS 17.2, was rendering `<br>` elements after position: absolute was applied to *

```
*{position:absolute;}
```

This made it so, according to Apple, Safari will conform to a recent css spec draft, where somebody didn't think through that developers need a reliable analogue to `\n` .  According to Apple, Safari will now permanently effect `<br>` elements by computing them absolutely as well.

My solution was to modify the css, by adding

```
br{position:relative;}
```

Worked like a charm, but, again, the line-break tag, for years in all browsers, was simply an analogue to `\n` , that could not -- and still cannot -- contain children, and was always meant to modify relatively, instead of being completely block-ified ; thus, the fact this has to be added is more than a bit annoying, as it will now break, or rather not add a break-line, for many older websites that used `*{position:absolute;}` to help designers/developers with div layering and pixel precision.